# Pass HTTPRequest parameter to another request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, url-parameters

In my CRUD MVC web application I have a `users.jsp` page that is called by `/users` servlet that displays a paginated table of users with buttons for each user that perform an action (e.g. grant admin privileges) but don't redirect to a separate jsp page. The action is performed by calling a separate servlet on button click:

```
<button formaction="changeUserRights">Grant admin rights</button>
```

The `changeUserRights` servlet performs the corresponding DB operation and calls

```
resp.sendRedirect("/users")
```

which renders pagination and redirects to `users.jsp`.

However, when I click the `Grant admin rights` button while being on page 2+ (e.g. `users?page=3`), the application redirects me to the default page `/users`.

How do I make the app stay on the same page, i.e. save the `page` parameter? I know how to save parameters as request attributes and pass them to other servlets within the same request, but here as far as I understand I'm creating a new request on button click. I guess I could save the parameter in `sessionScope` but I believe there's a better way. So how do I pass this parameter to the `/changeUserRights` servlet with this new request made from the jsp?

I read several posts on SO on how to stay on the same page, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608960/stay-on-the-same-page-after-inserting-into-db), but couldn't figure out how to apply it to my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was easy.

1. Update the jsp call to:

```
<button formaction="changeUserRights?page=${currentPage}">Grant admin rights</button>
```

where `currentPage` is a request attribute that's set by the service that performs pagination of pages in the web application.

2. Read the parameter in the `changeUserRights` servlet:

```
String pageNumber = "1";
if (req.getParameter("page") != null) {
    pageNumber = req.getParameter("page")
}
```

3. Pass the parameter when redirecting back to `/users`:

```
resp.sendRedirect("/users?page=" + pageNumber);
```